# CakePHP 2.x Field is Empty or null

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to run a query with many conditions but one of the conditions if I want to check if a field is null or empty, I've tried this without success:

```
$query['conditions']['team.product_group'] = ["", null];
```

This doesn't product the desired result, so I thought of trying OR

```
    $query['conditions']['OR'] = [
      'team.product_group' => "",   
      'team.product_group' => null,   
    ];
```

Umm I have a clash of array key now.

Is there another way to say if a field is a blank string or it's NULL?

Database is MySQL

Many thanks.

Comment: Instead of `'team.product_group' => null,` it should be `'team.product_group IS NULL'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
$query['conditions']['OR'] = [
  'team.product_group' => "",   
  'team.product_group IS NULL',
];
```

With there being multiple `OR` clauses in your `conditions` array now, this might work:

```
$query['conditions']['AND'] = [
  'OR' => [
    'team.product_group' => "",   
    'team.product_group IS NULL',
  ],
];
```

From the docs [`Complex Find Conditions`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions):

> You can create very complex conditions by nesting multiple condition arrays:

```
array(
    'OR' => array(
        array('Company.name' => 'Future Holdings'),
        array('Company.city' => 'CA')
    ),
    'AND' => array(
        array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('Company.status' => 'active'),
                'NOT' => array(
                    array('Company.status' => array('inactive', 'suspended'))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Ideally you'd avoid such flat value conditions, you'll loose automatic quoting support, and it's kinda encouraging for people that aren't aware of the security implications, to dynamically inject data into the string. Key conflicts can for example be solved by nesting the conditions into separate arrays.